# Docker compose run yarn install

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

When running the step **RUN yarn install** in a Dockerfile during docker-compose build command, I get:

> [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching packages... info
>   fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
>   info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed
>   compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. [3/4] Linking
>   dependencies... warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has
>   unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697". warning " >
>   webpack-dev-server@2.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0
>   || ^3.0.0". warning "webpack-dev-server >
>   webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency
>   "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0". [4/4] Building fresh packages...

but the node_modules folder is NOT created. On the other hand when I run

```
docker-compose run SERVICE_NAME yarn install
```

I get:

> [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching packages... info
>   fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
>   info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed
>   compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. [3/4] Linking
>   dependencies... warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has
>   unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697". warning " >
>   webpack-dev-server@2.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0
>   || ^3.0.0". warning "webpack-dev-server >
>   webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency
>   "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0". [4/4] Building fresh packages...

but then the folder **node_modules** IT IS created in the project folder.

I just don't understand why ... I'm expecting same functionality but I'm missing something.

Here my docker-compose service

```
services:
  ruby:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/ruby/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - some-network
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5

# Install dependencies:
# - build-essential: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
# - nodejs: Compile assets
# - npm: Install node modules
# - yarn: Install & manage node modules [should make npm obsolete]
# - libpq-dev
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs yarn \
    libpq-dev \
    mysql-client 

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

# install node dependencies
RUN yarn install

RUN bundle install
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the first case node_modules folder isn't generated inside container? Or may be you have `volume` mapping for that service?

Comment: after running docker-compose build, then I get inside the container and folder is not there. I edited my question in order to show you the service setup in the docker-compose file

Comment: Can you please provide `docker/ruby/Dockerfile` as well?

Comment: Dockerfile added

Comment: I see you already mapped your docker root path for `/app` path in docker-compose, so you don't need to copy in Dockerfile. If you want to copy all files to container, you must remove `volumes` part in docker-compose.

Answer (score 9):

At first creates an image depending on Dockerfile:

1. Get an image `ruby:2.5` to create new image from it
2. Install all dependencies
3. Create folder `/app`
4. Copy all files from your system (project directory) to image's `/app` path
5. Install `yarn` and `bundle` (call methods inside image)

And after that "mounts" your projects folder to image's `/app` folder, so it becomes same as your system root folder. After that "generates" container and executes `CMD` command from Docker file (if exists).

Take an account that ***this is not detailed explanation of image/container generation flow***, but hope it can help you to solve your problem. So you can

1. Run your code directly from container (as you done in Dockerfile)
2. or Don't copy source code to container and mount code as volume (as you done in docker-compose.yml), and execute `yarn install` in your system, or create entrypoint script with installation commands: `entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh`

***EXAMPLE OF FILES***

If you want to update your source files "on fly" (to see updates without rebuilding container), you must use second way.

Create file run.sh in your project directory:

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '--- run yarn install'
yarn install

echo '--- run bundle install'
bundle install

# HERE YOU CAN RUN ANY OTHER SCRIPT BEFORE CONTAINER BUILDING

echo '--- create docker image and up it'
sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

**docker-compose.yml**

No need to change (keep like in your question).

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5

# Install dependencies:
# - build-essential: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
# - nodejs: Compile assets
# - npm: Install node modules
# - yarn: Install & manage node modules [should make npm obsolete]
# - libpq-dev
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs yarn \
    libpq-dev \
    mysql-client 

WORKDIR /app
```

To build and up container **just run command**: `sh run.sh`

It will install node dependencies in your system, after that will create container, which `/app` folder will be your project folder (in your system), so your code changes will take an effect immediately.

Comment: By removing the mounted volume, I got the node_modules folder in the container but not in the host machine. Besides I can't modify files outside container. I need to map container folder with host in the IDE?

Comment: @Jordi You can not map container folder with IDE (even if you can via your container IP, it will cause a lot of problems: permissions, indexing speed, sync problem). Normal way to allow container read files from your system (which you done in `volume` section), but in that case you need to install dependencies in your system before container building. Please see updated answer (*EXAMPLE OF FILES* part)

Comment: I'd like to run docker-compose without a script. I tried this approach => https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/unifying-rails-environments-docker-compose, but I don't see the folders created after yarn install (already removed the copy part from the Dockerfile), not in the container and either in the mounted volume. The funny is when I get into the container and I execute "yarn install" then I see the "node_modules" folder in the mounted volume, but of course I want to get the same result within the Dockerfile

Comment: I don't know it's bug or not, but docker at first "executes" Dockerfile (until CMD command) after that mount volumes. 
If you want to run docker-compose without script, create bash file `entrypoint.sh`, write in it commands `yarn install` and `bundle install` and run your docker: `sudo docker-compose up -d --build`. Docker automatically will execute `entrypoint.sh` (so it just becomes part of your code). Hope that way can help.

Comment: I was doing your approach here in your last comment, but later I need to debug and realize that I couldn't set the remote sdk with docker-compose up to debug because of the entrypoint. Here is another question by me based on the same issue with all the files. Hope you can take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948058/docker-compose-ruby-not-installing-dependencies-with-yarn