# Docker compose missing yarn dependencies on build

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, yarnpkg

Can't get node_modules folder when running yarn install in the Dockerfile

```
test-sof
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "site",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "reactjs": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Dockferfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs yarn

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

ADD ./package.json /myapp/

RUN yarn install
```

output of the step RUN yarn install when **docker-compose build**:

> ```
> Step 6/6 : RUN yarn install
> ---> Running in 3a0e7095ec81 
> yarn install v1.3.2 
> info No lockfile found. 
> [1/4] Resolving packages... 
> [2/4] Fetching packages... 
> info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module. 
> info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. 
> [3/4] Linking dependencies... 
> warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697". 
> warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0". 
> warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0". 
> [4/4] Building fresh packages... 
> success Saved lockfile. 
> Done in 21.11s. 
> Removing intermediate container 3a0e7095ec81  
> ---> 5720579a0f2a 
> Successfully built 5720579a0f2a 
> Successfully tagged testsof_web:latest
> ```

Running command: **docker-compose run web bash** to get in the container

```
root@11af1818e494:/myapp# ls    
Dockerfile  docker-compose.yml  package.json
```

no node_modules folder present, but later when running inside the container: **yarn install** output:

> ```
> root@11af1818e494:/myapp# yarn install
> yarn install v1.3.2
> info No lockfile found. 
> [1/4] Resolving packages... 
> [2/4] Fetching packages... 
> info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module. 
> info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. 
> [3/4] Linking dependencies... 
> warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697". 
> warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0". 
> warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0". 
> [4/4] Building fresh packages... 
> success Saved lockfile. 
> Done in 13.03s.
> ```

then when listing:

```
root@11af1818e494:/myapp# ls    
Dockerfile  docker-compose.yml  node_modules  package.json  yarn.lock
```

folder node_modules IT IS present. Why?

Answer (score 7):

This part of `Dockerfile` installs yarn packages:

```
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD ./package.json /myapp/
RUN yarn install
```

Folder `/myapp` is created, `package.json` is copied to it and yarn packages are installed. Build is successful and, of course, `node_modules` folder is inside built image.

But after that you start built image with:

```
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
```

which means that content of folder where `docker-compose.yaml` is is mounted to `/myapp` folder inside container, so it covers content of container's `/myapp` folder.

You don't need to mount current folder to container's folder to achieve what you want. Just delete it from your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
```

Now you can:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose run web bash
root@558d5b0c2ccb:/myapp# ls -la
total 268
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Feb 23 22:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  65 root root   4096 Feb 23 22:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x 818 root root  36864 Feb 23 22:25 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    333 Feb 23 22:07 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 219075 Feb 23 22:25 yarn.lock
```

**EDIT:**

> But what I want is when building the image, get these dependencies not
>   when spinning up the containers. Otherwise I have another container
>   which mounts de source code and needs this node_modules folder when
>   running the "docker-compose up" and I'd like to avoid some kind of
>   ugly sleep until the node_modules is finished. So I need present this
>   folder on my root host before up the containers somehow

If you want to achieve the above goal, you can use the following workaround:

**1.** You modify `Dockerfile` a little:

```
FROM ruby:2.5

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs yarn

RUN mkdir /build && mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /build

ADD ./package.json /build/

RUN yarn install

WORKDIR /myapp

CMD cp -a /build/node_modules/ /myapp/
```

That's means that yarn packages will be built in `/build` folder inside image and copied to `/myapp` folder once container is started.

**2.** You use the original `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

when you start `web` container:

```
docker-compose up web
```

folder `node_modules` is copied to mounted folder i.e. to `.` folder on your host machine.

**3.** Now you can start any container and it will be contain `node_modules` folder inside `/myapp`:

```
docker-compose run web bash
```

So, you will be able to achieve your goal the following way:

```
$ docker-compose build && docker-compose up web
$ docker-compose run web bash
root@4b38e60adfa3:/myapp# ls -la
total 64
drwxrwxr-x   3 1000 1000  4096 Feb 24 10:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  66 root root  4096 Feb 24 11:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000 1000   497 Feb 24 10:55 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--   1 1000 1000    73 Feb 24 09:02 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 818 root root 40960 Feb 24 10:57 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   333 Feb 23 22:07 package.json
```

Comment: I see Nickolay thx.  But what I want is when building the image, get these dependencies not when spinning up the containers. Otherwise I have another container which mounts de source code and needs this node_modules folder when running the "docker-compose up" and I'd like to avoid some kind of ugly sleep until the node_modules is finished. So I need present this folder on my root host before up the containers somehow